# PHP Shopping Cart list only one item

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I am working on an onlinestore project. In my code,the shopping cart will only list 1 item. For example when i click add to cart button under iphone 5s it will jump to the cart and show me Iphone 5s with 1 quantity. However, when i press again Samsung, it will overwrite Iphone 5s and show me only Samsung.

Here is the code for product:

```
<div>
    <image src="ip5s.jpg">
    <p><font color="blue">&nbsp&nbspIphone 5S</font></p>
    <p><font color="red">&nbsp&nbspRM1999</font></p>
    <p><form name="addcart" method="post" action="processcart.php">
        <input type="submit" name="addtocart" value="Add to cart" >
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1234" />
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
    </form>
</p>
</div>
&nbsp&nbsp
<div >
    <image src="s4.png">
    <p><font color="blue">&nbsp&nbspSamsung Galaxy S4</font></p>
    <p><font color="red">&nbsp&nbspRM1999</font></p>
    <p><form name="addcart" method="post" action="processcart.php" >
        <input type="submit" name="addtocart" value="Add to cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1235" />
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
    </form>
</p>
</div>
```

Here is the processcart.php:

```
<?php
 session_start(); 
 include_once("config.php"); 
 $_SESSION['pid']=$_POST['product_id'];
 $_SESSION['qty']+=$_POST['quantity'];
 $_SESSION['cart']=true;
 sleep(2);
 echo "Add to cart successful";
 header("refresh:1;url=cart.php");
 exit();
 ?>
```

Here is the cart.php:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
    echo "<p>Your shopping cart is empty!</p>";
elseif (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_NAME", "onlinestore");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
    $tblname = "products";
    mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
    $proid = $_SESSION['pid'];
    $query = "SELECT * from $tblname where product_id='$proid'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo "<table>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['product_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['product_price'] . "</td></tr>";
        echo $_SESSION['qty'];
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION['pid']=$_POST['product_id'];` - this probably each time replaces product in the cart. Should be an array of products.

Comment: how do i make it an array?sorry that im new to php

Comment: You where to fast :D But another thing is that you should use `Mysqli_*` functions, instead of the `mysql_*` functions, because it is [Deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)

Comment: **Jelle Ferwerda** just pointed, how to make it an array, and **Mathlight** is absolutely correct about `mysql_*` functions. One could use `mysqli` or `pdo` these days : )

Answer (score 1):

edit:

from

```
 $_SESSION['pid']=$_POST['product_id'];
 $_SESSION['qty']+=$_POST['quantity'];
```

to

```
if(! isset($_SESSION['product']))
  {
  $_SESSION['product'] = array();
  }

 $_SESSION['product'][$_POST['product_id']] = $_POST['quantity'];
```

Then edit your processing to loop through the session & get each product.

Edit: You should consider using `$_SESSION['cart']['products'] = array();` as it makes more sense in the organisation side of your vars: Produacts are in the cart, and as such a part of your cart.

edit2:

This is how I would organized cart, based on using $_SESSION['cart']['products'] for storing products. Note: Untested code; Will probably have some typos. Just go through it and try to understand the logic:

```
// Move these into a different file, so you only have it once.
// Then use require_once('DatabaseConnection.php');

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "onlinestore");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
  {
  echo "<p>Your shopping cart is empty!</p>";
  }
else
  {
  $tblname = "products";
  require_once('DatabaseConnection.php');

  $prodids = array();
  foreach($_SESSION['cart']['products'] as $id => $qntity)
    {
    $prodids[] = $id;
    }
  $prodids = implode(',', $prodids);

  $query = "SELECT * from $tblname where product_id in ($prodids) ";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

  echo "<table>";

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['product_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['product_price'] . "</td></tr>". $_SESSION['cart']['products'][$row['product_id']];
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close();
```

Comment: When you implement the code above, your cart.php does not understand the way you have organized the session. As such, you need to moidify the cart.php

Comment: So can i use foreach loop to display?

$product=$_SESSION['product'];         foreach($product as $values){         echo $values;                   }

Comment: See comments on othe ranswer above; Stop using MYSQL functions; It is depreciated.

Comment: i do know the injection problem.i will modify it later.Thank you

Comment: There is still a problem in the foreach loop saying that invalid argument supplied

Comment: i dont understand this line $_SESSION['product'][$_POST['product_id']] = $_POST['quantity'];