# php display multiple items

Tags: php, arrays

I am using array to display the data after user click a button

Here is my code:

```
$items=array("1234"=>"Iphone 5S","1235"=>"Samsung Galaxy S4");
    $proids = $_POST['product_id'];
    echo $items[$proids];
```

Here is the code for products:

```
<div>
    <image src="ip5s.jpg">
    <p><font color="blue">&nbsp&nbspIphone 5S</font></p>
    <p><font color="red">&nbsp&nbspRM1999</font></p>
    <p><form name="addcart" method="post" action="processcart.php">
    <input type="submit" name="addtocart" value="Add to cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1234" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
    </form>
    </p>
</div>
<div>
     <image src="s4.png">
     <p><font color="blue">&nbsp&nbspSamsung Galaxy S4</font></p>
     <p><font color="red">&nbsp&nbspRM1999</font></p>
     <p><form name="addcart" method="post" action="processcart.php" >
     <input type="submit" name="addtocart" value="Add to cart">
     <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1235" />
     <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
     </form>
     </p>
 </div>
```

However this will only show one data.For example i click on the add button for Iphone5, it will redirect to page and show me Iphone5. After that i click on Samsung, it will redirect to page and overwrite the Iphone5 and show me Samsung.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Shopping Cart list only one item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814083/php-shopping-cart-list-only-one-item)

Comment: sorry for that, i am using array to do in here

Comment: Check your other question, php shopping cart display error, where I posted a more complete solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `quantity[]`, `product_id[]`

```
 <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="1235" />
 <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="1" />
```

PHP:

```
$product_ids = $_POST['product_id'];

 foreach($product_ids as $product_id){
      echo $items[$product_id];
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <form name="addcart" method="post" action="processcart.php">
   <div>
    <image src="ip5s.jpg">
    <p><font color="blue">&nbsp&nbspIphone 5S</font></p>
    <p><font color="red">&nbsp&nbspRM1999</font></p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="addtocart" value="Add to cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="1234" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="1" />

    </p>
</div>
<div>
     <image src="s4.png">
     <p><font color="blue">&nbsp&nbspSamsung Galaxy S4</font></p>
     <p><font color="red">&nbsp&nbspRM1999</font></p>
     <p>
     <input type="submit" name="addtocart" value="Add to cart">
     <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="1235" />
     <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="1" />

     </p>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i had done this but there is something wrong in this line:echo $items[$proids];

Comment: product_id post value is an array, So you need to use foreach to fetch the individual element.

Comment: erm~it gt no error,but it still showing me only 1 result

Comment: Updated my answer, Please check the html section

Answer (score 0):

> Not used same name for two component..
>
> Instead of these use **loop** for display component and accepting
>   values of component..

*Append loop variable to name of every component*